# How to use tablespace in django for this model

Tags: python, django, tablespace

I have some models with relations and i need to to use tablespace in that models , please help how i solve it .

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    # classe 365's id of the teacher
    classe_365_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    # email of the teacher
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    # first name of the teacher
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # last name of the teacher
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # Many to Many fiels with the subject, because a teacher can teach multiple subjects 
    # and also a subject can be taught by many teacher in same class
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField('Subject')

    #status for teacher is active or not
    # status =  models.BooleanField(default=True)
  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name
```

Comment: [went through this ?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/tablespaces/#:~:text=A%20common%20paradigm%20for%20optimizing,tablespaces%20to%20organize%20disk%20layout.&text=Django%20does%20not%20create%20the,on%20creating%20and%20managing%20tablespaces.)

what issue you are facing?

Comment: I have no idea how to use tablespace in django  , and i'm applying it first time on my this model  so i'm cofused how i do it , please let me know

Comment: it is mentioned in the link, you can try that first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.